# How can MySQL queries come in the wrong order?

Tags: php, mysqli, jenkins, phpunit

I have some code that creates a user and later down the line it checks if the user is real. Essentially this:

```
// INSERT statement fired in here
$user = self::_createUser( $params );

// Performs a sanity check by hitting DB with
// SELECT for the ID returned from creation within object
if ( !$user->isReal() ) {
  throw new Exception( "User failed to create: " . var_export( $params, 1 ), MYCODE );
}
```

Since the user was just created this exception should never be thrown. This never happens in production, or my sandbox environment. However our test environment uses Jenkins to kick off multiple tests at once, where the lines above live.

The exception will be thrown at random, on different tests at each run of our suite.

We turned on all MySQL logging and found that the sanity `SELECT` is being called BEFORE the `INSERT` however the `SELECT` is clearly selecting the proper ID from the DB - which it couldn't have unless the create worked.

How can MySQL server randomly receive a query in the wrong order? Never seen anything like this before.

**EDIT** Here is more code for clarification

```
function _createUser( $params ) {
  // db returns connection using Zend, which translates to something like
  // INSERT INTO users SET name='a'
  // Returns ID of row inserted
  $this->_id = self::db()->insert( 'users', $params );
}

function isReal() {
  // Returns false when row is not there
  return self::db()->fetchRow( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$this->_id}" );
}
```

Also the MySQL logs show the query as I expect in all cases, with NO `DEFER`

**EDIT 2** 
Using command line rather than Jenkins to run tests parallel is still making this happen.
Meanwhile it will only run up to 7 tests at the same time, and there no where in the code that would delete the user at the time. There are no blanket deletes except BEFORE all the tests run.

**EDIT 3**
Okay so in the tests that run, there are some persistent connections. One is for MySQL and one is for Mongo. Before my suite runs it was wiping MySQL by rebuilding DB from scratch, and erasing memcache. It was not doing this for mongo and thus was causing some other random errors. Once I added mongo to the reset script, it seems that the MySQL errors went away. This makes zero sense to anyone on my team or myself. Can anyone make sense of that?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple runs interfering with one another? As a side note: you should really look into mocking your database, there is no reason to actually call MySQL in the tests. PHPUnit has excellent support for mocking.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Even if my parallel tests are going same time, each test is a single thread. How would the test serially create and check, but MySQL would get it in backwards order?

Comment: I don't know, it shouldn't do that. It doesn't make sense. What you're seeing is probably something else. Maybe the logger is actually off?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen It's the actual MySQL log which fires the instant the query comes in and is not part of anything I've coded.

Comment: if the `SELECT` is actually selecting the correct ID (assuming it has received it from the `INSERT` query?), there is no way it can have run before the INSERT. However, I'm suspecting that the logs you see may be out of order, not the running of queries.

Comment: Do your `INSERT`s have `DEFER` on them perhaps?

Comment: logs may be out of order simply because writing to the log file sometimes takes a bit longer and so the next lines may already have been printed before previous one, if you get what I mean.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen we are working towards objects that can more easily mock the DB. I can't wait for that to be done. We know it selected the right ID since the "nonexistent" row is there in the DB after test runs and fails.

Comment: do you use any transactions?

Comment: I would definitely check the `INSERT` statement that's being generated, or write your own raw SQL statement to rule that out.

Comment: @YourCommonSense no transactions for this part.

Comment: @trpt4him based on logs and what the db actually has after the code runs, the `INSERT` is working

Comment: @FritsvanCampen no `DEFER` that I know of, but I'll double check and update question

Comment: @mavili according to logs, the `INSERT` happened thousands of lines later... I know I'm running parallel tests but that seems way too far to be delay but I'll double check on that too.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but are you using more than one database?  ie one for reading and another for writing?  or, is there some kind of parallel processing going on such as a gearman job?

Comment: Nothing gearman in this case. No slaves in sandbox, just one DB. I am going to make an update above of something ridiculous

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but two days later, this error went away. It went away like my 3rd edit said... after I made sure that when I emptied MySQL and memcache, I also emptied mongo. The best guess I have is that when bad mongo data caused an exception, PHP sputtered in some way. Not sure if it's a PHP bug or if I'd sound crazy trying to report it.

Although I'm posting this answer, I'd still appreciate any additional input.